# Python program throws error because it says it cannot find pygame even though I have imported it in the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pygame

```
import sys

import pygame

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Battle")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 3, in 
>   import pygame
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I have installed pygame and did the import command on the cmd on windows.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**If you have more than one python editor in your pc, make sure you installed pygame into the right python editor**

Comment: You are right. The programme works in IDLE but i am using PyCharm so how do i install the pygame in PyCharm.

Comment: Go to where your Pycharm is located, and somewhere there should be a 'pip.exe' file, maybe inside a folder called Scripts. Copy the address of the 'pip.exe', cd to the address in cmd, then run 'pip install pygame' in the cmd.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of problem arises because of two resiongs:

1. If you have more then on python version in your system and you don't set the python environment yet for default python version to use.
2. Some time editor not response well after installing packages or library. In this case just close the editor and restart it. Most of the time it helps to fetch the library.